# Keeping track of user customization's c#

Tags: c#

Good evening; I have an application that has a drop down list; This drop down list is meant to be a list of commonly visited websites which can be altered by the user.
My question is how can I store these values in such a manor that would allow the users to change it.
Example; I as the user, decide i want google to be my first website, and youtube to be my second.

I have considered making a "settings" file however is it practical to put 20+ websites into a settings file and then load them at startup? Or a local database, but this may be overkill for the simple need.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: How are you currently persisting your list (where are you loading it from, and where are you saving it)? Can you post the code?

Comment: It would depend on the amount of sites you are talking but for small amounts (100>) i see no issue with settings file.

Comment: Using the registry is another option.

Comment: I currently just have a list of sites i believe users will want to use however i believe the ability to pick sites that are relevant would be better and the options listed above (db / settings) seemed like the best 2 options - rufus L   Thanks @Pogrindis it is roughly 20-30 sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have already excluded database (probably for right reasons.. as it may be over kill for a small app), I'd recommend writing the data to a local file.. but not plain text..
But preferably serialized either as XML or JSON.

This approach has at least two benefits -

1. More complex data can be stored in future.. example - while order can be implicit, it can be made explicit.. or additional data like last time the url was used etc..
2. Structured data is easier to validate against random corruption.. If it was a plain text file.. It will be much harder to ensure its integrity.

Comment: +1 XML Serialization seems like it *could* also be overkill, but is definitely a good thing to consider.

Comment: Agreed.. I included XML for completeness, but JSON is certainly lighter than XML.. and has pretty good support for reading and writing now a days.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly need some sort of persistence, for which there are a few options:

1. **Local database**
        - As you have noted, total overkill. You are just storing a list, not relational data
2. **Simple text file**
       - Pretty easy, but maybe not the most "professional" way. Using XML serialization to this file would allow for complex data types.
3. **Settings file**
       - Are these preferences really settings? If they are, then this makes sense.
4. **The Registry** - This is great for settings you don't want your users to ever manually mess with. Probably not the best option for a significant amount of data though

I would go with number 2. It doesn't sound like you need any fancy encoding or security, so just store everything in a text file. *.ini files tend to meet this description, but you can use any extension you want. A settings file doesn't seem like the right place for *this* scenario.

Comment: Don't forget the Registry! :p

Comment: @RufusL Excellent point, I've added it. Not where I would put a list of anything though :)

Comment: Thanks you! I will steer clear of the settings file; I'm going to pursue the .ini file, seems like the best option for my needs! :)

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to use the power of Serializer and Deserializer in c#, which will let you work with the file in an Object Oriented. At the same time you don't need to worry about storing into files etc... etc...

Here is the sample code I quickly wrote for you.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class UrlSerializer
    {
        private static void Write(string filename)
        {
            URLCollection urls = new URLCollection();
            urls.Add(new Url { Address = "http://www.google.com", Order = 1 });
            urls.Add(new Url { Address = "http://www.yahoo.com", Order = 2 });
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(URLCollection));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            x.Serialize(writer, urls);
        }

        private static URLCollection Read(string filename)
        {
            var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(URLCollection));
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            var urls = (URLCollection)x.Deserialize(reader);
            return urls;
        }
    }

    public class URLCollection : ICollection
    {
        public string CollectionName;
        private ArrayList _urls = new ArrayList();

        public Url this[int index]
        {
            get { return (Url)_urls[index]; }
        }

        public void CopyTo(Array a, int index)
        {
            _urls.CopyTo(a, index);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _urls.Count; }
        }

        public object SyncRoot
        {
            get { return this; }
        }

        public bool IsSynchronized
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _urls.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(Url url)
        {
            if (url == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
            _urls.Add(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I attempted to implement this method however Url is not defined in the current context; It is throwing an error how do i make it so that Url is defined correctly